# A bug with the WolframAlpha computational search engine?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-software, computational-mathematics

I think I may have discovered a bug with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

So I was trying to determine all $x$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{5}{x^{-i}} < \frac{13}{12}.$$

WolframAlpha spit out $x > 13$ (see this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+%281%2Fx%29+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E2+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E3+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E4+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E5+%3C+13%2F12)).

However, when I double-checked,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{5}{{13}^{-i}} = \frac{402234}{371293} \approx 1.0833331\ldots.$$

Of course, we have

$$\frac{13}{12} = 1.08\bar{3}.$$

This means that $x = 13$ is a solution to the inequality

$$\sum_{i=0}^{5}{x^{-i}} < \frac{13}{12}.$$

Here are some more examples:

[WolframAlpha link 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+%281%2Fx%29+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E2+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E3+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E4+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E5+%3C+17%2F16)

[WolframAlpha link 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+%281%2Fx%29+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E2+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E3+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E4+%2B+%281%2Fx%29%5E5+%3C+29%2F28)

Does this mean that we can't trust WolframAlpha?

Comment: This might be a rounding error...

Comment: Yeah, if you click "More digits" you get more precise results.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i = 0}^5 \frac{1}{x^i}$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @DavidMehrle!  Good catch.  Editing my post now to reflect that change.

Comment: Good grief!  @Wojowu, can you write out your comment into an actual answer so that I may be able to accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: Why should you trust a computer answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A simple equivalent is trying to solve:

$$13x^5<x^6+12$$

So you are seeking solution to $f(x)=x^6-13x^5+12=0$. $x=13$ is a gross estimate, but it is not far off. If we take $x=13+\epsilon$ then $(13+\epsilon)^6-13(13+\epsilon)^5 + 12 = 0$ which, if we ignore exponents for $\epsilon$ greater than $1$ yields the equation:

$$13^6 + 6\epsilon \cdot 13^5 - 13(13^5+5\epsilon\cdot 13^4) + 12 =12 + \epsilon \cdot 13^5$$

So $$\epsilon\approx \frac{-12}{13^5}\approx -0.00003231948892$$

And even that is not perfect: $f(12.99996171721108)\approx -2.21$.

A more accurate answer is: $$x> 12.999967680123.$$

Then $$f(12.999967680123)\approx 0.0000050783$$

I don't know what WA used for rounding.  It only appears to use 6 digits of accuracy elsewhere, which would result in $x>13$.

If I ask WA to:

> `solve x^6-13x^5+12`

It returns $13.0000$.

When I ask WA to:

> `solve (13+x)^6-13(13+x)^5+12`

it returns $-0.0000323199$.

Comment: Since you found a bug on WA, you can submit a brief report by filling out the feedback form on the bottom of each query's page. Be sure to run the problematic query before submitting the feedback form.

Comment: It's not a bug - it is rounding to six digits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

13 is just a rounded output because you can find zeros of polynomial of grade grater then 4 just numericaly hence you can't get exact form. In fact, the more precise output is $x>12.9999677$ so 13 is still a good value. You can get more precise output just by clicking "more digits"

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica*, it suffices to enter the command

```
Reduce[Sum[x^-i, {i, 0, 5}] < 13/12, x, Integers]
```

Which gives the output (which I have interpreted) $$(x \in \mathbb Z) \cap (( x \le -1 ) \cup (x \ge 13)).$$

Unfortunately, Wolfram|Alpha does not support `Reduce[]` (for obvious reasons--if it did, why buy *Mathematica*?).  But if you enter this:

[Case x = 13](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F13%20%2B%201%2F13%5E2%20%2B%201%2F13%5E3%20%2B%201%2F13%5E4%20%2B%201%2F13%5E5%20%3C%201%2F12)

You will get `True`.